# serialize-javascript vulnerability found in yarn.lock

Tags: reactjs, npm

I created a React project using `npx create-react-app my-app` command. I then tested the project using `npm start`. When I commit the project to Github, I get a security advisory in the project page.

```
serialize-javascript vulnerability found in yarn.lock

**Remediation**

Upgrade serialize-javascript to version 2.1.1 or later.
```

I do not have the serialize-javascript dependency in my package.json file. Here is the project in Github - https://github.com/shankarps/ReactPracticeProject/

How can i fix this error?

How can i ensure that the latest dependencies are included in the project when it is created?

Comment: https://github.com/yahoo/serialize-javascript/releases version 2.1.1 and 2.1.2 were released just 12 hours ago. did you try upgrading?

Comment: Upgrading `yarn upgrade serialize-javascript@2.1.2` removes the security warning but doesn't update nested dependencies. I opened an issue about this https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17559

Comment: @AryeEidelman You can use https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8100

Answer (score 4):

This GitHub issue has a pretty good conversation on this:
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4986

"The workaround of adding sub-dep A as a direct dep just to fix a security issue is worse because it creates confusion (the package is not used directly) as well as a maintenance burden." - kumar303

As a couple others have suggested, adding a resolutions field to your package.json file might be more ideal. 
"resolutions": {
    "serialize-javascript": "^2.1.1"
  }

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue Reported by GitHub for my React app created by `npx create-react-app`:

[image]

Here is what I did to resolve this security alert for serialize-javascript to do with yarn.lock.

```
yarn add serialize-javascript
```

And then git commit and push [the changes of package.json and yarn.lock](https://github.com/yucigou/graphql-local-state-management/commit/a4865c02a9049235f3084ef7c0e5da1129537324) to GitHub. As a result, the alert was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `serialize-javascript` in the resolutions inside `package.json` so you can force it to use the last update. then run `yarn upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue occurred me, tried below ways and worked

1) `yarn add serialize-javascript
     git add .
     git commit -m "Message here"
     git push origin master`

2) Add resolutions in **package.json** file 
   `"resolutions": { "serialize-javascript": "^2.1.1" }`
  and try `yarn upgrade`

Answer (score -1):

From https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17559#issuecomment-563457352

> There's nothing about React apps that requires the use of this plugin. It's just something being used by react-scripts/Webpack.

One partial solution is to add the yarn.lock file to the .gitignore. That way the alert will not be shown.

Comment: Adding `yarn.lock` to `.gitignore` is not a wise solution if you intend to deploy to production environments.